# Laravel 5 checking if two record do exists in table through laravel:5 query

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, laravel-5, web

```
**$auth** = Authentication::where(['registration','=',Input::get('registration'),'transcript_serial','=',Input::get('transcript_serial')])->first();


if (is_null(**$auth)** ){return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('registration'));**strong text**}

   print_r("this part of database");
}
```

Sorry in Advance I'm beginner of Laravel.

Basically I wanna authenticate the user that already exists in database like school Management System.
I have a Authentication Model which is handling authentication table `('id','registration','transcript_serial');`
 this code is only check one attribute it's could be `registration` or `transcript_serial` but my requirement is it should check both record in the authentications table then I will redirect to next page. Please guide me.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
$auth= Authentication::where('registration','=',Input::get('registration'))->where('transcript_serial','=',Input::get('transcript_serial'))->first();
if(empty($auth)){
  return 'success';
 }else{
  return 'already exist';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the record match with your requirement, Check with the condition.

You don't need to add `=` If you want to check for equals to, it is added by default.

```
$auth = Authentication::where('registration',Input::get('registration'))->where('transcript_serial',Input::get('transcript_serial'))->first();
OR
$auth = Authentication::where(['registration' => Input::get('registration'),'transcript_serial' => Input::get('transcript_serial')])->first();
if(!$auth){
    return 'success';
}else{
    return 'already exist';
}
```